# java spring entity manager holding false entities after new saveAndFlush calls

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently writing tests and I fail to understand why I don't get the correct entities when calling my findOne method on a repository.

My test setup works like this

- parent = ParentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);
- child.setParent(parent);
- child = ChildRepostiroy.saveAndFlush(child);

Now when calling

```
parentRepository.findOne(parent.getId());
```

It will return the correct parent, but It will not (yet) have the connection to the child. The child relation is null. However when calling

```
entityManager.clear();
```

before the findOne it will work as expected. I'd think that the entitymanager is able to identify changes without clearing it. At least the findOne method should invalidate the cache, shouldn't it?

I'm using hibrenate-jpa-2.1. For the repositories I'm using the JpaRepositoryAndSpecificationExecutor interface.

The tests are running with the following annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@Transactional
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Hibernate uses lazy loading of references to avoid loading too much data during query operations.

You may enable eager loading to overcome this or use the getter method to actually load the reference.

From https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/

> FetchType.LAZY = Doesn’t load the relationships unless explicitly
>   “asked for” via getter FetchType.EAGER = Loads ALL relationships

Comment: eager loading is definitly not a solution. It's lazy on purpose and it is definitly not the problem as it would be able to load the relation via the proxied object.
Besides that it fully works after calling entitymanager.clear() which should already inditcate the the loading itself is not the problem. The EntityManager seems to keep the entities in it's cache and simply returns the references. However the references are not equal to what you would get when reading it from the database.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the point it would appear. Sorry about that. Then as you say, findOne is trusting the cache and not clearing it would apperar. Reading the docs for findOne, http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findOne(ID), there is no mentioning about findOne invalidating the cache. It probably shouldn't, it would defeat the purpose of having a cache to begin with if you are going to go and check against the database to see if the value in the cache is up to date in every  find query